# Ribbon not showing in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

How can I get the link that looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Ribbon x:Name="RibbonWin"  SelectedIndex="0">          
        </Ribbon>        
</Grid>
```

I get an error saying

```
The type 'Ribbon' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

I added the ***Windows.System.Controls.Ribbon*** reference

I've also added the reference path as documented on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6taasyc6(v=vs.80).aspx

I am using WPF with .Net framework 4.5 on Windows 8.1

The application must run on Windows 7 (and higher)

Comment: As always when something ribbon related comes up anywhere, do yourself a favor and use Fluent.Ribbons instead of WindowsRibbons as they are so much less buggy and include Office 2010 + 2013 styles. https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon

Comment: Which Visual Studio do you use? I just did exactly what you did and it works without any problems in VS 2013

Comment: Did you try using VS2013? Maybe there is a bug in VS2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the *Ribbon control* to the *Toolbox* in VS2015, then simply drag-and-drop the Ribbon-associated controls (e.g. Ribbon Tab, Ribbon Group, Ribbon Button, etc) from the Toolbox into your previously-added Ribbon in the `MainWindow.xaml` form at design-time.

To add the Ribbon control to the Toolbox in VS2015, simply right-click within the Toolbox in VS2015 (with your project opened), select the Choose Items... option which will bring you to the Choose Toolbox Items dialog window (as depicted in the screenshot below), from which you will select the WPF Components tab, then scroll down and check all the options which pertain to the Ribbon controls to add them to your Toolbox when you click on OK.

Screenshot of the *Choose Toolbox Items* dialog window:
[image: Screenshot of the *Choose Toolbox Items* dialog window]